# Pycharm / Django defer Oracle Database connection

Tags: python, django, oracle

I have a Django project that connects to an Oracle database - implemented in PyCharm. I would like the app to monitor the connection and display a status as to whether the database is up or down. I stopped the listener to simulate an error. However, when I start the PyCharm server to test the functionality, the app immediately attempts a database connection and fails. Is it possible to defer the database connection until I can command one within the app?

Here is the error traceback on server startup:

---

C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/steve/PycharmProjects/Tools/Tools/manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py", line 229, in get_new_connection
return Database.connect(
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
self.check_migrations()
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 486, in check_migrations
executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in **init**
self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 53, in **init**
self.build_graph()
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 220, in build_graph
self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
if self.has_table():
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 259, in cursor
return self._cursor()
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 235, in _cursor
self.ensure_connection()
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in **exit**
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Tools\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py", line 229, in get_new_connection
return Database.connect(
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Comment: "Is it possible to defer the database connection until I can command one within the app?" maybe .... however, you've not shared anything of the application with us; only a stack trace that contains no particularly useful information. Please attempt a solution and then ask a question on the issues/errors with **your** code.

Comment: There's not really much to add. I have created a Django application, add the cx-Oracle packages, define the Oracle credentials in the settings.py file, and start up the server. If the database is good, my app opens. If the listener is down, I get this stack trace. At some point when the server starts up, it attempts a database connection and fails. I would like to know how to defer that attempt and put it under explicit control of the app.

I can't think of anything else that would help to enlighten the question.